# Importing Json field from csv to MySQL 5.7.19-0ubuntu0.16.04.1

Tags: mysql, json, csv

I have MySQL table consisting of 3 columns having type of `(cookie vachar, userdata json, userprefernce json)`. I am trying to load the data from csv but it gives the following error :

**Error:**

`Error Code: 3140 Invalid JSON text: Invalid value at position 0 in value for column userdata'`

I have tried to validate the JSON it looks fine. Now I couldn't understand what is the problem

**Sample Row:**

```
ZwpBHCrWObHE61rSOpp9dkUfJ, '{"bodystyle": {"SUV/MUV": 2}, "budgetsegment": {"EP": 2}, "models": {"Grand Cherokee": 1, "XC90": 1}}', '{"bodystyle": "SUV/MUV", "budgetsegment": "EP", "models": "Grand Cherokee,XC90"}'
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't reproduce the problem:

File: `/path/to/file/data.csv`

```bash
ZwpBHCrWObHE61rSOpp9dkUfJ, '{"bodystyle": {"SUV/MUV": 2}, "budgetsegment": {"EP": 2}, "models": {"Grand Cherokee": 1, "XC90": 1}}', '{"bodystyle": "SUV/MUV", "budgetsegment": "EP", "models": "Grand Cherokee,XC90"}'
```

MySQL Command Line:

```sql
mysql> \! lsb_release --description
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS

mysql> SELECT VERSION();
+-----------+
| VERSION() |
+-----------+
| 5.7.19    |
+-----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `table`;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `table` (
    ->   `cookie` VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
    ->   `userdata` JSON NOT NULL,
    ->   `userprefernce` JSON NOT NULL
    -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/path/to/file/data.csv'
    ->   INTO TABLE `table`
    ->   FIELDS TERMINATED BY ', '
    ->          OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\''
    ->   LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 1  Deleted: 0  Skipped: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> SELECT
    ->   `cookie`,
    ->   `userdata`,
    ->   `userprefernce`
    -> FROM
    ->   `table`\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       cookie: ZwpBHCrWObHE61rSOpp9dkUfJ
     userdata: {"models": {"XC90": 1, "Grand Cherokee": 1}, "bodystyle": {"SUV/MUV": 2}, "budgetsegment": {"EP": 2}}
userprefernce: {"models": "Grand Cherokee,XC90", "bodystyle": "SUV/MUV", "budgetsegment": "EP"}
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```